# haxe: get line number and line position from haxe.macro.Position

Tags: macros, haxe

In haxe macro for every expression we can get it's position in form of http://api.haxe.org/haxe/macro/Position.html :

```
 {
   file:String, // filename - relative to source path
   min:Int, // position of first character in file
   max:Int // position of last character in file
 }
```

I want to get line number and position in line for min and max variables.

I definitely can do this by opening the file

```
FileSystem.absolutePath(Context.resolvePath(posInfo.file));
```

and calculating line number, but haxe already does this, it's much better to get this info from compiler. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your actual problem?

Comment: I'm making debugger by insert my code between every expression in every function with macros. And I need line positions for this. I made it by manually parsing files, but I still think it's better to get this info from compiler.

Answer (score 2):

In the current versions of Haxe you can use `PositionTools.toLocation`

```
class Macro {
    public static macro function log(args:Array<Expr>):Expr {
        var loc = PositionTools.toLocation(Context.currentPos());
        var locStr = loc.file + ":" + loc.range.start.line;
        args.unshift(macro $v{locStr});
        return macro SomeExtern.logFunc($a{args});
    }
}
```

to have `Macro.log("hi!")` translate into `SomeExtern.logFunc("Main:5", "hi!")`

Answer (score 0):

I know a few projects do that manually (like checkstyle)

Load the file content, find the carriage returns (\n, \r or \n\r) mark the character position for each new line, lookup your pos.min against those positions

I guess it might be more problematic if you have multibyte characters in the file ...

Answer (score 0):

In haxe 4 `PositionTools.toLocation` function was added.